# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException on SQLite get

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get data from an SQLite table and I know that table will always have only one record. I'm trying to do that get using:

```
public User_Token getUser_TokenDB() {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_USER_TOKEN  +" WHERE ID = " + 1;

    Cursor cursor = this.database.rawQuery(sql, null);

User_Token auxUserToken = new User_Token(
        cursor.getLong(0),
        cursor.getString(1),
        cursor.getString(2),
        cursor.getString(3));

return auxUserToken;
}
```

But I always get:

```
'java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.support.android.iplfit/com.support.android.iplfit.Activities.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0'.
```

The only way I can access this information is by returning an array of Tokens and do .get(0) but I feel like it is not the right way, since it has no sense to return an array of only one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor index starts out of bounds. You need to use `Cursor#moveToFirst()` which moves the cursor to the `0` index and returns `true` if there are items in the cursor.

So something like this:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   // Cursor has items and is ready for extraction
} else {
   // Cursor has no items.
}
```

Comment: how should I handle my return outside the moveToFirst() condition ?

Comment: @NelsonSilva Return `null` because the user token doesn't exist.

Comment: Otherwise just take the first element if you can guarantee that there will only ever be one entry that matches the query. No reason to return an array then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `cursor` at first row before you can get data from it. Call `moveToNext` method before accessing data from `cursor`

```
while(cursor.MoveToNext()) {
    User_Token auxUserToken = new User_Token(
        cursor.getLong(0),
        cursor.getString(1),
        cursor.getString(2),
        cursor.getString(3));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't **moving** to a position within the cursor, thus the location is before any rows i.e. -1.

You need to move to a row and in your case you want the first row (*not that there are any* *(i.e. the message says* ***size of 0***)) and only if the move can be made do you want to extract data. Otherwise you would handle no data available.

The Cursor `move????` methods (`moveToFirst`, `moveToLast`, `moveToNext`, `moveToPrevious`, `moveToPosition`) all return true if the move can be made, otherwise false.

So your code code be :-

```
Cursor cursor = this.database.rawQuery(sql, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst) {

    User_Token auxUserToken = new User_Token(
    cursor.getLong(0),
    cursor.getString(1),
    cursor.getString(2),
    cursor.getString(3));
} else {
  return null; //???? handle no data how you want perhaps null.
}
return auxUserToken;
```

---

*As a note it's inadvisable to generally use column offsets, rather the more common way is to get the offset according to the column name using `getColumnIndex(column_name)`. So (assuming the column name is **`id`**) would be to replace `cursor.getLong(0)` with `cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")`*

Comment: I appreciate the code but that way I cant access my auxUserToken variable in the return since it is initialized inside the if statement.

Comment: @NelsonSilva hence the comment *???? handle no data how you want*, returning null is a possibility.